# How to add dynamic elements to an object in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am sorry if I am asking a very basic question, I have done some research over the internet but not getting anything useful.

I have a typescript object like :

```
var productIds=["one","two","three"];

let searchfilter = {
    or: [{
        id: { match:productids['0'] }
    },{
        id: { match:productids['1'] }
    },{
        id: { match:productids['2'] }
    }]
};
```

My productIds can be dynamic and may hold different counts of values.

How can I create the same structure for a dynamic number of values. I tried `forEach`, but not sure about the syntax.

```
productids.forEach(function(value){
// not sure if this is right syntax, I am not getting desired results.
    searchfilter.or = { id: { match:value }};
});
```

Can you help me with it?

Comment: I don't see anything related to [tag:typescript] above, can you clarify? Is your issue with doing the work, or with defining the types? Your code looks like JavaScript, not TypeScript (but sometimes TypeScript can infer so much that TypeScript code *does* look like it's just JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

You can create your full `or` array with a simple `.map()` :

```
var productIds = ["1", "2", "3"];

let searchfilter = {
    or : productIds.map( n => ({ id : { match : productIds[n] } }))
};
```

However Mongo (which I believe you are using) has a `$match` method that's made to match a list :

```
{
    $match: {
        productIds: {
            $in: productIds
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll keep it as simple as I can

```
var productIds=["one","two","three"];
let searchfilter =  productIds.map(p => {
  return {id: { match: p }};
});

// function
addNewProduct(id: string) {
   this.searchfilter.push({id: { match: id }});
}
```